# What does $B\log_2(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})$ tend to as $B\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: limits

As the title explains, what is does $B\log_2(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})$ tend to as $B\rightarrow\infty$?

For context, $C = B\log_2(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})$ is Shannon's theorem, and I'm curious as to what the capacity is as the bandwidth is made infinite.

Thanks!

Comment: Try L'Hospitals rule. This function has the same behaviour as $x \log \frac{1}{x}$ which could simplify the computation.

Answer (score 0):

For small positive $x$,
$x-x^2 
\lt \ln(1+x)
\lt x$
so,
since
$\log_2(x)
=\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$,

$B\log_2(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})
=\dfrac{B}{\ln(2)}\ln(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})
\lt\dfrac{B}{\ln(2)}\dfrac{P}{N_0B}
=\dfrac{P}{\ln(2)N_0}
$
and
$B\log_2(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})
=\dfrac{B}{\ln(2)}\ln(1+\frac{P}{N_0B})
\gt\dfrac{B}{\ln(2)}(\dfrac{P}{N_0B}-\dfrac{P^2}{N_0^2B^2})
=\dfrac{P}{\ln(2)N_0}-\dfrac{P^2}{\ln(2)N_0^2B}
$
so the limit
as $B \to \infty$ is
$\dfrac{P}{\ln(2)N_0}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{P}{N_0B}=x$ that is to say $B=\frac{P}{N_0 x}$ to make 
$$B\log_2\left(1+\frac{P}{N_0B}\right)=\frac{P }{N  \log (2)}\frac{ \log (1+x)}{ x }$$ 
$$\lim_{B\to \infty } \,B\log_2\left(1+\frac{P}{N_0B}\right)=\frac{P }{N  \log (2)}\,\lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{ \log (1+x)}{ x }$$

Use Taylor series or L'Hospital rule to get the result.